# How to get friend/business partner to view and edit Lex bots with me in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

> I was recommended to ask this question here when I attempted to ask it in StackOverFlow, but then some moderator deleted my question without telling me why. If this is the wrong place to ask this kind of question, they can at least direct me to a site that is appropriate for my specific issue instead of being very passive-aggressive. And no, I don't care if said moderator further retaliates because I can just post such questions on other platforms that don't have power tripping clowns. Well, well, well...why am I not surprised about that moderator's true colors? Hypocrite much - complaining about SO being elitist and hostile, but then acts that way himself to a new user such as myself.

Long story short, I want my friend who's also my partner in my startup to help me with developing, testing, and deploying AI chatbots in Amazon Lex via AWS. I have him registered as a user in Identity Center (previously known as Amazon SSO), and have provisioned the SystemAdministrator permission set for him. It has the SystemAdministrator and AmazonLexFullAccess policies attached to it, so in theory he should be able to access the bots without any restrictions. Problem is, he can't seem to view the bots as if they don't even exist, yet I can see and access the bots from my end. I've attempted to edit the resource-based policies, only to discover that my bots being in draft mode limits what can be done to them even if permissions/policies are granted.

Also, I previously was confused and assumed IAM and Identity Center were the same thing or at least connected, but the AWS CLi revealed he's not even an IAM user. I would go with IAM for registering users, although Amazon themselves recommend to use Identity Center, and I feel that they might one day deprecate it (and also I'm too lazy to learn how to use it). I can of course export the bots and allow him to import it or attempt editing RAM, but those bring extra complications themselves. When I did publish my bots prematurely, I discovered these bots become read-only despite what the official AWS documentation and AmazonQ bot told me (AWS' tech support chatbot). I also tried reading through AWS documentation, searching online, and asking various LLM chatbots like ChatGPT, Perplexity, and Bing AI.

I think he just has to change the region from Sydney to North Virginia, as when I changed the regions (and based on what the LLM bots told me), I too couldn't view the bots either even though I'm the root user. Neither of us have really any experience with AWS and while he has had some experience using Azure, his experience in AWS is nearly equal to mine lol. I don't really care how he can access it, as long as he can view and edit the bots with me, so anyone who has any ideas can tell me here. If this question is off-topic and/or irrelevant and it's better for me to post elsewhere, kindly tell me where to post instead of downvoting because if you care so much about digital points, please touch some grass.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lvwc3.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2uDP.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1gI2.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3pff.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fBex.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lkm0a.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFS7g.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATFgh.png

Comment: I would strongly recommend a basic course like the AWS Cloud Practitioner, if neither of you have any experience with AWS. There is also https://skillbuilder.aws/.

Comment: Also, side note - naming and shaming mods probably doesn't help your case if you're trying to get people to respond to your question. SF has a rule about questions being relevant in a professional business setting, and there's an assumed level of knowledge. We get a lot of questions about home media servers and the like, so lots of stuff gets flagged as off-topic. Some people may read your post and assume it's the same, given the lack of basic AWS knowledge. There are lots of great free AWS training materials and documentation on the web.

Answer (score 0):

If the bots were created in e.g. the Sydney region, they only exist in the Sydney region. You will always need to check that you're on that region in the dropdown in the top right before they appear. Some services are 'global' and will revert you to N. Virginia when viewing them, so if you don't see what you expect, check the region.

If you still can't see them in the region in which they were created, then you'll need to provide some more information on how they were created and where.